# How to reduce the size of spatial index data

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to reduce the size of spatial index data?
is there any way to compress the location details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data_compression option is not supported for spatial index in SQL Server 2008, According to Microsoft Documentation, support for data compression was added for spatial indexes in SQL Server 2012. SQL Server adds support for index compression of spatial indexes, using the same options as data and index compression in SQL Server 2012 and above.

> As Microsoft Documentation specifies about DATA_COMPRESSION :-

```
 DATA_COMPRESSION = {NONE | ROW | PAGE}
```

> Applies to: SQL Server 2012 (11.x) through SQL Server 2017, SQL Database.
>     Determines the level of data compression used by the index.

```
NONE
No compression used on data by the index

ROW
Row compression used on data by the index

PAGE
Page compression used on data by the index
```

Using compression with spatial indexes appears to be quite effective.You may obtain between 25-40% reduction in size with ROW compression and 50-90% reduction in size with PAGE compression. Queries that use a compressed spatial index execute in about the same (in some cases, less) CPU and elapsed time as the same queries using uncompressed spatial indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a few options you can tweak to reduce or increase it's size. However, knowing exactly what implications they bring might require investigating a little.

- Use `DATA_COMPRESSION` option. Default is `NONE`, you can use `ROW` or `PAGE`.
- Modifying the `FILLFACTOR` ratio.
- Use a custom tesellation grid with lower cells per object/level. This will greatly impact on how "useful" the index becomes when doing "seeks".